# Change the text color on WPF Calendar?

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar

I want to change the text color for special days on WPF Calendar.

I have researched the topic http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882520.aspx, at the item `"The RedLetterDays Display"`, it showed how to highlight the special days, but I want to change the color of special days only.

I read the code in XAML file, and I saw the important line

```
 <Rectangle x:Name="RedLetterDayBackground" IsHitTestVisible="False" Fill="#80FF0000" />\
```

The author use the rectangle to highlight special days.

Someone can show me how to edit this XAML code to solve my requirement, or if you have a other way to do it?

Many thanks,

T&

Comment: Your question is worded just a bit unclear. Do you want to change the special day text's foreground color?

Comment: Yes, I want to change the special day text's foreground color!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your DataTrigger's target to the `TextElement` in `CalendarDayButton` instead of `RedLetterDayBackground`, will achieve the change you want.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource conv}}" Value="{x:Null}">
   <Setter TargetName="CalendarDayButton" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Red" />  
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Thanks! I pasted your above code in <ControlTemplate.Triggers>, but It show the error "The name 'CalendarDayButton' is not recognized". Please show me how to create 'CalendarDayButton'. Thank you so much!

Comment: re-reading the article you sent I think this `DayTitleTemplate` that contains a `TextBlock` element which controls the foreground brush. But I can't download the source to inspect the code myself due to my work firewall's restriction on zip files from MSDN.